# Can't import hyperlink to Open Refine

Tags: openrefine

I imported an `.xlsx` file where one of the columns is filled with `hyperlinks`, but the links don't show on OpenRefine, just the value.

1. Does it happens only on `Linux` or it's the same thing with `Windows`?
2. If not, is there any other way to import those `hyperlinks`?

Answer (score 0):

OpenRefine will not load the link from an XLS or XLS or ODS file in general.

You need to extract those link first into a new column in Excel. A quick search pointed to this tutorial: [Excel: convert a column with hyperlinks to just display the links](https://superuser.com/questions/430260/excel-convert-a-column-with-hyperlinks-to-just-display-the-links)